# Proof Strategy: For all nonzero complex numbers $z$ and all nonzero rational numbers $a$ and $b, \mathbb Q (az+b)=\mathbb Q(z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, proof-verification

I am having trouble proving (or finding a counterexample but I believe it to be true) the following. Prior to this I did some problems such as: Show that $\mathbb Q (-3+i\sqrt{2},2-\sqrt{8})=\mathbb Q (i,\sqrt{2})$ and I didn't really encounter any difficulty (providing I did them correctly). My idea was to apply the same strategy I used before on the following:

**Prove or give a counterexample:** For all nonzero complex numbers $z$ and all nonzero rational numbers $a$ and $b, \mathbb Q (az+b)=\mathbb Q(z)$ and $\mathbb Q (az^2+b)=\mathbb Q(z)$

What I did doesn't feel right. I just copied the same procedure as the other problems but I have no means to determine if this was appropriate or not. Here's what I did for $\mathbb Q (az+b)=\mathbb Q(z)$:

We need to show two things:

**(1)** $\mathbb Q (az+b)\subseteq \mathbb Q(z)$, and
**(2)** $\mathbb Q (az+b)\supseteq \mathbb Q(z)$

For **(1)**: Since $\mathbb Q (az+b)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing the subfield $\mathbb Q$, and the element $az+b$, it suffices to show that $\mathbb Q (z)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$ which contains $\mathbb Q$ and $az+b$.

$\mathbb Q (z)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb Q(z)$ and by definition $a,z,$ and $b$ are all in $\mathbb Q(z)$. Since $\mathbb Q(z)$ is a subfield, $az+b$ is in $\mathbb Q(z)$ as well. Thus, since $\mathbb Q (az+b)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing the subfield $\mathbb Q$ and $az+b$, $\mathbb Q (az+b)\subseteq \mathbb Q(z)$.

For **(2)**: Since $\mathbb Q(z)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing the subfield $\mathbb Q$, and the element $z$, it suffices to show that $\mathbb Q (az+b)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and $z$. By definition, $\mathbb Q(az+b$ is a subfield of $\mathbb C$ which contains $\mathbb Q$.

Furthermore, since $a,b,$ and $z$ are in $\mathbb Q (az+b)$, $z=((az+b)-b)(a)^{-1}$. Thus, it follows that since $\mathbb Q(z)$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb C$ containing $\mathbb Q$ and $az+b$, $\mathbb Q (az+b)\supseteq \mathbb Q(z)$.

I did the same thing for $\mathbb Q(az^2+b)$. Can anyone verify if this makes any sense?

Comment: This is obviously false for $az^2+b$. Take $a=1,b=0$ and $z=\sqrt{2}$. Also, you need $a\neq 0$ for $az+b$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Is the first part good if I add in the part about $a\ne 0$?

Comment: Wait, I forgot that this is for all nonzero complex and all nonzero rational. So, both $a$ and $b$ cannot equal $0$. Would that change anything for $az^2+b$ though? We could let $b=1$ and get $\mathbb Q(3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: But you realize that ${\mathbb Q}(3)$ and ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2})$ are not the same, don't you ? ${\mathbb Q}[3]={\mathbb Q}$ since $3\in{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: Yes. When I said $\mathbb Q(3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ I meant that it was false and planned on using that as a counterexample.